# Can I sleep on a airplane tray table?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

Or rather, how heavy can the airplane tray table support?

I am afraid that if I use one of those flight pillows (https://familyshop.notyourchild.com/products/travelsky-inflatable-travel-pillow-foldable-for-airplanes-train-sleeping-flocking-pvc-soft-head-neck-rest-support-travel-pillows-2) and assert my upper body onto the tray, it might break.

Comment: The question is: how heavy are you?

Comment: How would you sleep on an airplane table tray without being in an extremely uncomfortable position and/or unbearably contorting your body?

Comment: When you are trying to sleep the seat in front of you will probably be at maximum recline, not almost upright as in the linked picture.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/PassengerShaming/videos/619143471901794

Comment: [The tray table is one of the dirtiest places on aircraft](https://www.travelmath.com/feature/airline-hygiene-exposed/).

Comment: How tall/big are you? In many cases, the tray table is actually resting on my knees, so it's as sturdy as my knees :-)

Comment: I see this all the time on the unfortunate large number of red eyes that I'm flying. So at least on United it's perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

This is not regulated as far as I am aware. The [Cabin Safety Subject Index](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/cabin_safety/media/cabinsafetyindex.pdf) does not even mention the tables nor do [14 CFR § 25.785 - Seats, berths, safety belts, and harnesses](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.78).